# Converting PKCS#12 certificate into PEM using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, command, pkcs#12

I have OpenSSL x64 on Windows 7 which I downloaded from [openssl-for-windows on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip). I'm attempting to run:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "path.p12" -out "newfile.pem"
```

but I get an error.

```
unable to load private key
```

How do I extract the certificate in PEM from PKCS#12 store using OpenSSL?

Comment: @jww I think given that this question is over 3 years old that it is a bit late to signal the off-topic flag.

Comment: Just a formality so folks know its off-topic. People are asking the same off-topic questions, and citing this question. If folks are not told its off-topic, then they will continue to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jww the highest voted answer on the meta question you link says "DevOps questions should be allowed on Stack Overflow." I will upvote, because the answer met my needs (although, for me, I wasn't programming, I could easily incorporate the answer in a program if I wished)

Answer (score 797, accepted):

Try:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
```

After that you have:

- certificate in newfile.crt.pem
- private key in newfile.key.pem

To put the certificate and key in the same file without a password, use the following, as an empty password will cause the key to not be exported:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.pem -nodes
```

Or, if you want to provide a password for the private key, omit `-nodes` and input a password:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.pem
```

If you need to input the PKCS#12 password directly from the command line (e.g. a script), just add `-passin pass:${PASSWORD}`:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys -passin 'pass:P@s5w0rD'
```

Comment: Is it possible that private key and certificate would be stored in the same *.pem file?

Comment: yes, it is: `openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.pem`

Comment: asking for  Import Password . what is that ?

Comment: @SaurabhChandraPatel you have to know the password for your certificate.  This isn't a means to recover a forgotten password

Comment: @SaurabhChandraPatel For me it was the Apple ID password.

Comment: omitting -nodes, the private key does not get extracted.

Comment: @SaurabhChandraPatel If you don't know the password, maybe the password is empty. Try with `-passin pass:` to express an empty password.

Comment: thank you @ValerioBozz for suggestions. I think you are little bit late as this was in 2016 :-)

Comment: in openssl pkcs12 help screen it says that `-nodes` parameter was deprecated in favor of `-noenc`

Comment: When using the above commands, I got an error like this:

Error outputting keys and certificates
F07D0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:../openssl-3.1.1/crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:341:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()

Adding this option: -legacy solved it, in all commands.

Answer (score 26):

You just need to supply a password.  You can do it within the same command line with the following syntax:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "path.p12" -out "newfile.pem" -passin pass:[password]
```

You will then be prompted for a password to encrypt the private key in your output file.  Include the "nodes" option in the line above if you want to export the private key unencrypted (plaintext):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in "path.p12" -out "newfile.pem" -passin pass:[password] -nodes
```

More info: http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs12.html

Answer (score 19):

If you can use Python, it is even easier if you have the `pyopenssl` module. Here it is:

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

# May require "" for empty password depending on version

with open("push.p12", "rb") as file:
    p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(file.read(), "my_passphrase")

# PEM formatted private key
print crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())

# PEM formatted certificate
print crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate())
```

Comment: Is there any reason to open the file using `file` and not `open`? I just want to understand it as I am going to use it in future (to simplify my solution calling openssh as command)

Comment: Nope, no difference. You can just do `open("push.p12", 'rb').read()`.

Comment: If using python 3 you'll probably want to write the contents to files: ```with open("push.pem", "wb") as fobj: fobj.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))``` to write the cert and ```with open("push.key", "wb") as fobj: fobj.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))``` for the key.

Comment: I'm using python 3.7, when running the above example, I get the following: "TypeError: initializer for ctype 'char' must be a bytes of length 1, not str"  Is there something wrong with my password

Comment: Why is it "even easier" to create a file, enter the code, save it, and run it -- rather than just executing a single command?

Comment: You can automate with a script.

Comment: So, updated code will be:
`from OpenSSL import crypto

# May require "" for empty password depending on version

with open("push.p12", "rb") as file:
    p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(file.read(), "my_passphrase")
with open("push.pem", "wb") as fobj: 
    fobj.write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_certificate()))
with open("push.key", "wb") as fobj: 
    fobj.write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey()))   `

Comment: Please submit an edit to the answer. Pasting code into comments doesn't really work.

Answer (score 12):

There is a free and open-source GUI tool [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) to work with crypto key containers. Using it you can export a certificate or private key into separate files or convert the container into another format (jks, pem, p12, pkcs12, etc)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

On Macbook M1 with `openssl` installed through `homebrew` i had to add `-legacy` option:

`openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -out certificate.pem -noenc -legacy`

Answer (score 4):

I had a PFX file and needed to create KEY file for NGINX, so I did this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.pfx -out file.key -nocerts -nodes
```

Then I had to edit the KEY file and remove all content up to `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`. After that NGINX accepted the KEY file.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from optparse import Option
from OpenSSL import crypto
import os
import warnings
from getpass import getpass
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 

def sanitize_path(path):
    return os.path.expandvars(os.path.expanduser(path))

def main(in_file, out_file, passphrase=None):
    if not passphrase:
        passphrase = getpass(prompt=("SSL Private Key Passphrase: "))
   
    in_file = sanitize_path(in_file)
    out_file = sanitize_path(out_file)
    
    with open(in_file, "rb") as input_file:
        p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(input_file.read(), passphrase)
        pem = crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, p12.get_privatekey())
    with open(out_file, "w") as output_file:
        output_file.write(pem.decode('utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from optparse import OptionParser
    usage = "usage: %prog  input_file output_file [passphrase]"
    p = OptionParser(usage=usage)
    opt, args = p.parse_args()
    main(*args)
```