# Python Requests - SSL error for client side cert

Tags: python, certificate, python-requests

I'm calling a REST API with requests in python and so far have been successful when I set `verify=False`.

Now, I have to use client side cert that I need to import for authentication and I'm getting this error everytime I'm using the `cert (.pfx). cert.pfx` is password protected.

```
r = requests.post(url, params=payload, headers=headers, 
                  data=payload, verify='cert.pfx')
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.py", line 65, in <module>
r = requests.post(url, params=payload, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=cafile)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 88, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 346, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 449, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 322, in send
raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:2158)
```

I've also tried openssl to get `.pem` and key but with `.pem` and getting `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`

Can someone please direct me on how to import the certs and where to place it? I tried searching but still faced with the same issue.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I had this same problem. The `verify` parameter refers to the server's certificate. You want the `cert` parameter to specify your client certificate.

```
import requests
cert_file_path = "cert.pem"
key_file_path = "key.pem"

url = "https://example.com/resource"
params = {"param_1": "value_1", "param_2": "value_2"}
cert = (cert_file_path, key_file_path)
r = requests.get(url, params=params, cert=cert)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry didn't respond earlier, but that seemed to fix the issue! Appreciate your response.

Comment: how did you extract cert and key from the .pfx?

Comment: You should not set `verify=False` in most cases as that disables verification of the server's certificate which makes the whole connection insecure and vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. If you are connecting to a server with a certificate that's issued by a well known CA, then don't specify `verify` at all. If you are connecting to a server with a certificate issued by a private/custom CA then you should pass the path to that CA's certificate as the value of the `verify` parameter (if the server's cert is self-signed, then treat the server's cert the same as a CA cert).

Comment: @ierdna .pfx is a synonym for .p12 which is PKCS#12 format, converting to PEM with OpenSSL is covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144046)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and to resolve this, I came to know that we have to send RootCA along with certificate and its key as shown below,

```
response = requests.post(url, data=your_data, cert=('path_client_certificate_file', 'path_certificate_key_file'), verify='path_rootCA')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In hindsight it makes sense that the server would need my root cert to validate CA certificate, but this was the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to transfer a certificate directly from the Windows certificate store?
From what I understand, the requests library only accepts the file path. are there any adapters or other libraries that make it as easy as requests?

```
cert_name = "NAME CERT IN CERT STORE"
def export_cert_to_pem(cert, pem_path):
    pem = cert.get_pem()

    with open(pem_path, "w") as pem_file:
        pem_file.write(pem)


def find_cert_in_trusted_roots(cert_name):
    for storename in ("CA", "ROOT"):
        with wincertstore.CertSystemStore(storename) as store:
            for cert in store.itercerts(usage=wincertstore.SERVER_AUTH):
                if cert.get_name().lower() == cert_name.lower():
                    export_cert_to_pem(cert, cert_name + ".pem")

                    #export_cert_to_pem(cert, pem_path)
                    return 1

    return 0




cert=find_cert_in_trusted_roots(cert_name)
response = requests.post(some_url, data=your_data, cert=cert)
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the original question or a separate question?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, but I am running in Windows operating system within a corporate environment with custom TSL or SSL certificates. I would highly recommend using  the [`pip_system_certs`](https://gitlab.com/alelec/pip-system-certs) package. This package redirects `requests.get()` to use default operating system store certificates.

Install package with:

`pip install pip_system_certs`

My solution involved deploying a standalone python executable to download a file, so I had to include `import pip_system_certs.wrapt_requests`. Note, `# noqa: F401` is to ignore flake8 linting error just for this line.

```
import sys
import os
# 'import pip_system_certs' must occur before 'import requests'
import pip_system_certs.wrapt_requests  # noqa: F401
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
  
  installerUrl = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.8/python-3.10.8-amd64.exe"
  userPath = os.environ.get("USERPROFILE")
  installerPath = os.path.join(os.environ.get("USERPROFILE"), "temp_python_setup", os.path.basename(installerUrl))
  
  if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(installerPath)):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(installerPath))
  
  print(f"Installer Path='{installerPath}'")
  print(f"Installer URL='{installerUrl}'")
  
  downloadSuccessful = False
  proxy = {"http": "http://127.0.0.1:9000", "https": "http://127.0.0.1:9000"}
  
  try:
    with open(installerPath, "wb") as f:
      print("Downloading %s" % installerPath)
      response = requests.get(installerUrl,
                              stream=True,
                              verify=True,
                              allow_redirects=True,
                              proxies=proxy)
      totalSize = response.headers.get('content-length')
      if totalSize is None:  # no content length header
        f.write(response.content)
      else:
        totalSteps = 80
        downloadedSize = 0
        totalSize = int(totalSize)
        for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
          downloadedSize += len(data)
          f.write(data)
          downloadedSteps = int(totalSteps * downloadedSize / totalSize)
          sys.stdout.write("\r[%s%s]" % ('=' * downloadedSteps, ' ' * (totalSteps - downloadedSteps)))
          sys.stdout.flush()
      downloadSuccessful = True
      print(" ")  # end the progress bar
  except Exception as e:
    print(" ")  # end the progress bar, which may or may not have been started
    print(f"Error downloading {installerUrl}: {repr(e)}")
  
  if downloadSuccessful:
    print("\nDownload completed successfully")
  else:
    print("\nDownload failed")
```