# SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError) when presenting client side cert and key

Tags: apache, ssl, python-requests, mutual-authentication

I have a website that is hosted behind company's network. You could only connect to it using the `client.crt` and `client.key`. This `client.crt` is signed by a self signed `ca.crt` which is referenced in the `apache` config file.

I installed the server certificate `(servercrt.crt)` on my machine and can make a curl request with no issues:

```sh
curl https://my_url.com:53234 --cert path/to/client.crt --key path/to/client.key
```

I also imported the `client.crt` in the browser. When navigate to the `url` the browser asks to select the client certificate. Once selected the right client certificate, it opens up the page without issues.

However, I have problems with python. When I try to connect using python:

```py
import requests
clientcertfile = './client.crt'
clientcertkeyfile = './client.key'
servercert = './servercert.pem'
requests.get(url='https://my_url.com:53234, cert= (clientcertfile, clientcertkeyfile), verify = servercert)
```

I get the following error:

```
SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')
```

But, I can connect to this url when set the `verify=False` which I don't want. The requests package just displays a warning that its better not to set the `verify=False` option.

I have looked at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576324/python-requests-ssl-error-for-client-side-cert), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576324/python-requests-ssl-error-for-client-side-cert) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509902/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-using-pip-to-install-packages) but no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is not the client certificate but the verification of the server certificate. With curl you *added* the server certificate to the existing ones, with the browser too. With python you instead rely exclusively on the server certificate, so this could be one problem. The other might be that the server certificate has not basic constraints CA:true, which is needed though when used as a trust anchor in Python/OpenSSL. Check with `openssl x509 -in servercert.pem -text`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was using the wrong ca.crt for the server. Once I replaced it with the right certificate. It fixed the issue.

@Steffen's comment helped solved the issue.