# Can't convert .p12 to .pem with openSSL

Tags: firefox, openssl

After running this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.crt.pem -clcerts -nokeys
```

I get prompted with the option descriptions.

After running this

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes
```

I get prompted with "Enter Import Password:". What is this import password? I tried the one I set from the firefox backup and it responded with "Mac verify error: invalid password?". I'm sure that the password is correct because I tested it by importing it again into firefox.

I got the commands from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144046/need-help-converting-p12-certificate-into-pem-using-openssl)!

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but for my case the .p12 file was only necessary for the authentication at the CA website where I created my account. After authenticating I could generate a key and a certificate in .pem format which I could use on my server. That was my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing too. Try to put the password in the command line like this. It works for me:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes -password pass:<mypassword>
```