# How do i add ssl certificate to nodejs application to get authorised access to banking API

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, node-https

I am trying to use SSL secured api which Two Way SSL Authentication.
Have already created self signed certificate using keytool -genkey command and created 3 key files (selfsigned.crt , selfsigned.p12, selfsigned.jks) which is  shared with API provider. and one UATSKY.crt certificate given by API provider is added to my trust store on mac.
now when i try to access this api from post man it gives me pop up to select certificate after which it makes successful call api and get positive response.how do i achieve same in Node JS application.

I tried using https.createserver and passing ptivate key and  certificate to the craeteserver

```
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({

extended: false

}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

app.use(cors());


var privateKey =             
fs.readFileSync('./private/selfsignedpayeazzy.p12');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./private/selfsignedpayeazzy.crt');
var credentials = { 
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
 };

https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(port);
```

This is gives me following error

```
_tls_common.js:112
  c.context.setCert(cert);
            ^

Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:112:17)
at Server.setSecureContext (_tls_wrap.js:960:27)
at Server (_tls_wrap.js:850:8)
at new Server (https.js:61:14)
at Object.createServer (https.js:83:10)

not able to add this certificates to the application.
```

Comment: I'm guessing you know to check this already, but... is that certificate in PEM format?  Can you show the command line you used to generate it?

Comment: You need to convert those files to PEM format. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15144560/1531054

Comment: @Brad it was not in PEM format 

keytool -genkey -alias www.secureapi.com -keyalg RSA -keystore selfsigned.jks -validity 365 -keysize 2048

keytool -list -alias www.secureapi.com -v -keystore selfsigned.jks

keytool -export -alias www.yesbank.com -file selfsigned.crt -keystore selfsigned.jks

Comment: @S.D. I tried converting those file to PEM, 

   var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private/selfsigned.crt.pem');
   var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./private/selfsigned.key.pem'); 
   var credentials = { 
    key: privateKey,
     cert: certificate
     };

and added still gives the same error.