# How do I install SSL certificate on my ubuntu server

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have been given a  .pfx file and a pass key. How do I install ssl certificate on my ubuntu server through cli. The server is nginx.

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate should be installed on your webserver directly. Please edit your question with a server name you have running on Ubuntu instance (e.g. Apache, Nginx, etc.) The further flow will depend on your webserver specifically.

As for SSL certificate file you have, that is a file in PKCS#12 standard. It contains your end-entity certificate in pair with Certification Authority bundle along with private key. As was aforementioned, SSL installation flow depends on a particular webserver. You will need to convert the certificate in the PEM format (3 separate files: end-entity certificate, CA bundle, and the private key) for SSL installation on most common servers like Apache or Nginx. PKCS#12 file can be converted to PEM via openssl according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15144560/12385916).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make https calls, do install openssl on ubuntu machine and create a certificate using following commands (use sudo before every command, if required)

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem
openssl x509 -req -days 9999 -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out cert.pem
rm csr.pem
```

To check https is working or not, use following code

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

Test it on https://localhost:8000 or https://domain_name:8000