# convert decoded pkcs12 key to pem format

Tags: rsa, private-key, pem, pfx, pkcs#12

I'm trying to reverse engineering an app and I'm seeing that it encrypt an string using RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding method

before this it's loading something similar to a private key from another string with a method called "1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3" I googled this and found out that it's a PKCS12 key

I don't have access to the codes and I'm reading this data using frida so I don't understand what’s being done actually.

What I need to do is to be able to do the same rsa encryption so I need the key for rsa

I have a sample input and output to try and test if the key is right or not. I also have a hex string which I'm guessing it’s from a pfx file, another hex string generated from the previous one which looks like a private key and another smaller hex string which might be the password for pfx (I'm not sure about this)

On further investigation I found out that class name for the key is : `com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.PKCS12Key`

This is also the second hex string (replaced part of it with X) that I think is kind of a private key but I wasn't able to verify it :
`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`

what I tried until now :

converted the first hex string to binary and saved it into a file and then used `openssl pkcs12 -in -out` command to get pem formatted file, but it failed with error `4630589100:error:0DFFF0A8:asn1 encoding routines:CRYPTO_internal:wrong tag`

Comment: Kindly note that Stackoverflow is not a free code breaking or reverse engineering service.

Comment: @MichaelFehr who asked about doing free reverse engineering? I just have a problem about private keys conversion :)

Comment: I don't know who wrote the first sentence in your question "I'm trying to reverse engineering an app" but that's off-topic here on SO, sorry.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I was just trying to describe my situation :)

Comment: What type of application do you hook into using Frida? Android, iOS, Java Windows/Linux native program? BTW: "1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3" does not indicate that it is a PKCS#12 file, it just references a specific key generation method `pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC` that is used in PKCS#12, but it can also be used outside of an PKCS#12 file.

Comment: @Robert it's Android, also on further investigation I found out the class name of the key : com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.PKCS12Key But I'm not familiar with it ... So I'm kind of stuck in this step

Comment: This is probably your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15144046/converting-pkcs12-certificate-into-pem-using-openssl . Note that if you don't have the pkcs12 file password breaking it is not trivial and probably in the realm of black hats

Comment: it would be easier to decompile the APK and search for it in the code because default android obfuscation just scrambles the keys and not the values. your lucky if they didn't put it in NDK because that gets converted to SO file which is not really easy to reverse engineer.

Comment: @ofirule no it's not

Comment: @AliMomeni I tried, but it is obfuscated and couldn't get much out of it.